# Entity recognition based on context

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to get the probability of a word belonging to an entity based on context of the sentence.
For example (entity : server_name)

"I want to check mogo server"
And the result would be for example:

> Mogo : server_name , 0.5688999

"Check status of server mogo"
And the result would be for example :

> Mogo : server_name , 0.6272772

One solution would be for example to map all server names in a txt file or entity reco to do so...but in this case the names of servers can be quite a big number so each time we want a probability of a word being indeed a server name ,and so check the database/json for the server name ( if it exist we continue) if not we ask the user based on that probability if (mogo)is indeed a server name 
Like that we add it to the database 
So any way to use nltk,spacy or rasa to extract a word as an entity based on the sentence (not on words .txt or labels) and get the probability of the word with highest potential of belonging to a named entity?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CRF](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-sklearn_crfsuite) classifier. For each of the words in the sentence, you can get the probability scores.

[CRF](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-sklearn_crfsuite) expects the training data to be in [IOB format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging))

Here is a good [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-and-classification-with-scikit-learn-f05372f07ba2) about NER detection using CRF.

Example

```
crf_.predict_marginals_single(sent2features_for_prediction("Bengaluru"))


[{'O': 0.0008245389052411774,
  'B-entity__location': 0.9764201257123432,
  'I-entity__location': 0.003916777298076389,
  'B-entity__other_ent': 0.003445348786883558,
  'I-entity__other_ent': 0.00012730443363195458,
  'B-entity__other_ent_2': 0.005445385992475527,
  'B-entity__other_ent_3': 3.704781572842554e-05,
  'I-entity__other_ent_3': 2.1092149059526482e-05,
  'I-entity__other_ent_2': 0.00011894529348380328,
  'B-entity__other_ent_4': 2.0753893397695066e-05,
  'I-entity__other_ent_4': 6.333056114953314e-05,
  'B-entity__other_ent_5': 0.009492141753363492,
  'I-entity__other_ent_5': 6.720740516588521e-05}]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer assuming you want to do this in a rasa chatbot project. [`DIETClassifier`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#id20) can extract custom entities based on your training data. By additionally using [lookup tables](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/training-data-format/#id2) for your server names, you can increase the recognition of many different server names without exploding the number of training examples.

The underlying classifier for entities in DIET is CRF; practically speaking, both sentence context and the word itself contribute to whether or not a word is recognized as a specific entity. For example, if your training data contained examples like

```
 - I want to check [mogo](server) server
 - Check status of server [mogo](server)
 - check [mongo](server) server status
```

there's a good chance `mongo` in the unseen sentence `I want to check mongo status) would also be correctly picked up (based on sentence context).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by train your own data using Spacy. Spacy has good documentation of how to create and train your own custom model you can check [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training/)